# High CPU usage in System.net.Socket.beginReceive()

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I have a server software that has a single listening socket that then spans off multiple sockets (10 -30) which I then stream data to.

If I startup my application it used about 2-3% cpu usage on my 8 vCPU VM. After some time, generally 1-2 weeks the application suddenly starts using 60-70% cpu usage, and the thread count seems to stay stable, it does not increase.

I have run my C# profiler on my code and it comes down to the following line of code `System.net.Socket.beginReceive()`.

I am using `.net async sockets`. below is my `ReceiveCallBack` My suspicion is that I am not handling the case when `bytesRead` is NOT `>0`. How should I modify my function below to handle that case correctly?

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SocketState tmpRef = null;
            try
            {
                if (ar != null)
                {
                    tmpRef = (SocketState)ar.AsyncState;
                    if (tmpRef != null)
                    {
                        // Read data from the client socket. 
                        int bytesRead = tmpRef.WorkSocket.Client.EndReceive(ar);
                        //Start Reading Again
                        tmpRef.BeginReading(tmpRef._receievCallbackAction);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            // Check if we have a complete message yet
                            for (var i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                            {
                                if (tmpRef._receiveBuffer[i] == 160)
                                {
                                    var tmpBuffer = new byte[i];
                                    Array.Copy(tmpRef._receiveBuffer, tmpBuffer, i);
                                    //Execute callback
                                    tmpRef._receievCallbackAction(tmpBuffer);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (tmpRef != null)
                {
                    //Call callback with null value to indicate a failier
                    tmpRef._receievCallbackAction(null);
                }
            }
        }
```

Full code:  (Sorry don't want to dirty the post)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqjtz0r3ppgd11f/SocketState.cs?dl=0

Comment: Better add all the code, not just a piece of it (at least at the code were the supposed offending line is).

Comment: @Gusman I added link to full code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if you do not have enough bytes yet your code spins forever waiting for the next byte to show up.

What you need to do is make a `messageBuffer` that survive between calls and write to that till you have all the data you need. Also, by the way your code looks you look have the opportunity to overwrite `tmpRef._receiveBuffer` before you have copied all the data out, your `BeginReading` needs to start after the copy if you are sharing a buffer.

```
public class SocketState
{
    private readonly List<byte> _messageBuffer = new List<byte>(BufferSize);

    //...

    /// <summary>
    /// Async Receive Callback
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar"></param>
    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SocketState tmpRef = null;
        try
        {
            if (ar != null)
            {
                tmpRef = (SocketState)ar.AsyncState;
                if (tmpRef != null)
                {
                    // Read data from the client socket. 
                    int bytesRead = tmpRef.WorkSocket.Client.EndReceive(ar);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        //Loop over the bytes we received this read
                        for (var i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                        {   
                            //Copy the bytes from the receive buffer to the message buffer.
                            tmpRef._messageBuffer.Add(tmpRef._receiveBuffer[i]);
                            // Check if we have a complete message yet
                            if (tmpRef._receiveBuffer[i] == 160)
                            {
                                //Copy the bytes to a tmpBuffer to be passed on to the callback.
                                var tmpBuffer = tmpRef._messageBuffer.ToArray();
                                //Execute callback
                                tmpRef._receievCallbackAction(tmpBuffer);
                                //reset the message buffer and keep reading the current bytes read
                                tmpRef._messageBuffer.Clear();
                            }
                        }

                        //Start Reading Again
                        tmpRef.BeginReading(tmpRef._receievCallbackAction);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (tmpRef != null)
            {
                //Call callback with null value to indicate a failier
                tmpRef._receievCallbackAction(null);
            }
        }
    }

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explaining that the problems occurs after 1-2 weeks, which is quite rare then.
I would suggest you to orientate your researchs by improving the exception handling in your readcallback.

Within this exception handling it turns out that you are invoking the `callbackAction` with null.

Maybe you should consider answering the following questions :

1. How does the callbackAction behaves when invoked with null `tmpRef._receievCallbackAction(null);`
2. What kind of exception is caught? If it is a SocketException, maybe look at the ErrorCode, which might give you an indication
3. Would it be possible to dump the stack trace to know exactly where it fails ?

Some other weak point : the begin receive uses `this` as state object.
`WorkSocket.Client.BeginReceive(_receiveBuffer, 0, BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, this);`

So it means that the thread safeness of the readcallback is not entirely guaranteed, because the call to `BeginReading` will occurs while you didn't process the `_receiveBuffer`yet.